# CPU usage of coreaudiod on macOS with Apache Guacamole on FireFox

Tags: firefox

A single tab in Firefox opened with [Apache Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/) increases the use of cpu by 4-5% by the coreaudiod demon. If, for instance, I open 5 tabs, the CPU usage of coreaudiod is about 20%. When closing the tabs, the cpu usage of coreaudiod drops to 0%.
You need to be logged into Guacamole to see this happening.

The same doesn't happen with Google Chrome.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: It is not just Apache Guacamole, youtube does it to for me, but also other sites. It is super annoying

Comment: On my Mac, the  coreaudiod's CPU usage rises with youtube only when a video is playing but only by 2-3%. Only opening a youtube tab doesn't make any effects on the CPU.

Comment: There are a few reports about coreaudo and FireFox Web Content threads just eating cpu and memory on Mozillas bugzilla for firefox :)